# Slice sheet columns and paste in unique order?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, slice

I have a script which performs as intended however the current slice method in place is pasting an incorrect range.

Currently the script copies columns 1-12(A:L) and paste columns 1-5(A:E), skipping 6(F), and pasting columns 7-12(G:L) as-is.

I would like to have the script paste columns 1-5(A:E), skipping 6(F), pasting column 7(G), skipping column 8(H), and pasting column 9(I) with data from column 9(I) if "Absence" or data from column 11 if "late Arrival".

```
function Copy() {
    var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet id");
    var ss = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1"); 
    var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
    var data = ss.getRange(lastrow, 1, 1, 12).getValues();
    var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet id"); 
    var ts = tss.getSheetByName("Sheet 2"); tab name    
    var tslastrow = ts.getLastRow();    
    ts.getRange(tslastrow + 1, 1, 1, 5).setValues([data[0].slice(0,5)]); 
    ts.getRange(tslastrow + 1, 7, 1, 6).setValues([data[0].slice(6)])      
}
```

Comment: What's the issue that you're encountering with adjusting your code? Or is there no issue, but you just don't know how to do it? If the latter, then you need to review the `Array#slice` JavaScript method, and the `Sheet#getRange` Apps Script method, and try to implement it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

I understood what you want to do as follows.

- Source: Retrieve A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K and L from a row.
- Destination: Put A, B, C, D, E, G and (I) to a row.

  - About "I", when "K" is "late Arrival" or "I" is "Absence", add "I".

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modified script :

After the elements were retrieved by `slice()`, joined elements using `concat()`. At this time, it used the condition for column "I".

```
function Copy() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet id");
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
  var data = ss.getRange(lastrow, 1, 1, 12).getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet id");
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName("Sheet 2");
  var tslastrow = ts.getLastRow();

  // Below script was modified.
  var r = data[0].slice(0,5).concat(data[0].slice(6,7));
  if (data[0][8] == "Absence" || data[0][10] == "late Arrival") {
    r = r.concat(data[0][8]);
  }
  ts.getRange(tslastrow + 1, 1, 1, r.length).setValues([r]);
}
```

#### References :

- [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

If I misunderstand what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Hey Tanaike, 

I actually made a slight mistake regarding the configuration of the destination.

Comment: I would like to have pasted as follows:

Source: Retrieve A:F and I:L from last row.

Destination: place A:E as-is, skip over column F, place copied column F data as-is into destination column G, skip over column H, column I should contain column 9 data if column F was "Absence" or column K data if column F was "Late Arrival". 

Hopefully this is understandable. Please address if possible.

Comment: @Charles R. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I couldn't notice about the issue of question was different from your actual one. I'm really sorry for this. About your actual issue, I couldn't understand what you want. Can you provide an image or sample spreadsheet for input and output you want? If you can do, please update your question using it, because it was found that your question is not your actual issue. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.